# Why won't SQS throw an error when maximum in-flight messages is reached for a FIFO queue?

Tags: amazon-sqs

The approximate maximum number of in-flight messages for an SQS Standard queue is 120'000. When this limit is reached the `OverLimit` error message is returned. [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#inflight-messages)

But no error message is returned for FIFO queues in that case (limit here being 20'000 in-flight messages). [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#inflight-messages)

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's going to be an objective answer here, other than "it was an architectural decision."

The in-flight limit is something you should essentially never encounter -- it's only applicable to messages that have been delivered to consumers, not deleted, and not past visibility timeout.

The OverLimit error is only applicable to *receiving* messages -- not sending them.  You can still send messages to either type of queue when it's in this state, you just can't receive them.

Presumably, FIFO treats this as an ordinary "no messages available" situation so that the consumer is able to continue long polling as normal rather than seeing an exception, which would increase the workload on the FIFO queue -- which has a [300 transaction per second limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) that is not applicable to non-FIFO queues.  The 300 trx/sec limit includes any combination of send, receive, and/or delete, with each transaction batching up to 10 messages, and appears to be a limit related to the overhead required for coordinating exactly-once, in-order delivery.  You would not want a consumer seeing exceptions to increase the workload (and reduce the throughput) on the FIFO queue by continuously retrying, when something has already gone awry (as already evidenced by 20K in-flight messages).